# PHP, foreach only output "1"

Tags: php, foreach

The code is simple but the output is confusing me.

```
$dirnames = scandir($dir);
```

**The array of $dirnames :**

> Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => 0 [3] => 001 [4] => 009_1

```
foreach ($dirnames as $name) {
    if($name =! NULL){
echo $name;
}}
```

The output of echo is:

> 11111

After the loop.

Comment: *Hint, hint:* Your if statement is basically this `if(($name = (!NULL)))`

Comment: Your foreach sample code doesn't appear to be valid syntax. Can you double check and edit the question if your file is slightly different.

Comment: hint: `echo` is not the best tool for debugging. beware of the conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in

```
if($name =! NULL)
```

You should change it to:

```
if($name != NULL)
```

The first of the two is an assignment. It assigns to `$name` the boolean negation of `null` which is `true`, and so the `if` condition is always fufilled. Finally, the boolean `true` is echoed as `1`.

The second of the two is a comparison, which is what you intended.

Comment: Thanks, i got it fixed with if($name != NULL).